Help building a diagram block of Lima's paper approach
I hope this message is been placed in the right channel.
I'm trying to replicate the approach of the attached paper, Intelligent Control of Cardiac Rhythms using ANN, but even using other Nonlinear Control bibliographies to help me, I've not been able to understand the flow of the processes involved. And for that, I can't build a block diagram to visualize the loop control. Could you help me with that?
For now I know that Lima's approach uses Sliding Mode Control and Radial Basis Function to control and to approximate uncertainties present in the reference signal by the plant's output. Also, the mathematical model employed is based on a sixth-order Delay Differential Equation (three nonlinear Van der Pol oscillators adapted with time couplings), which is approximated by the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method.
Maybe after that I will be able to develop the MATLAB code for simulate some examples etc.

Welcome to Engineering SE. Please visit the [tour] page if you have not already done so. Please [edit] your question to include what you have already understood including the parts of the block diagram you have already built. Please also make the question more specific than "could you help me with that?".

The linked paper has a section called "Data availability The computer code used in the simulations, including both model and control parameters, can be accessed at ". Have you tried reading the code they provide?

Yes! I even tried to rewrite the code, which is in C++, to Matlab. However, I still don't understand how the approach flow works. That's why I was trying to build a block diagram to visualize the "links" between the components/functions/systems, like those for learning basic control theory...
|Reference|--->+------>|PID|------>|Plant|------->|Output|; and the negative feedback.
